# How to get started using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, compiling

I just spent an hour trying to understand Bibtex, but I find it very hard to find simple instructions. I even read half of the manual. I put this in my LaTeX file `report.ex`:

```
% preamble

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

% ...
% document

blaha \cite{guyton-hall}

\printbibliography
```

In `refs.bib`, I put:

```
@book{guyton-hall,
    author = {Guyton, Arthur C. and Hall, John E.},
    day = {01},
    edition = {11},
    howpublished = {Hardcover},
    isbn = {0721602401},
    keywords = {physiology},
    month = sep,
    publisher = {Elsevier Saunders},
    title = {Textbook of medical physiology},
    year = {2006}
}
```

What now? The manual talked about running `bibtex` on my AUX file, but then bibtex complains:

```
$ bibtex report
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: report.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file report.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file report.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file report.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

That happens after running `pdflatex report.tex` a couple of times. What am I doing wrong? And why is it so hard?

(And why should I even run `bibtex` when I'm using `biblatex` and `biber`?)

Comment: @lockstep: It worked! Thank you! Any idea what I could do if I want `biber`?

Comment: The reason I used `biber` first was that `biblatex` told me so due to UTF8 encoding. Later, I also read in the manual that bibtex and bibtex8 have problems with long citation lists.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Did you run `bibtex`, `biber` or both? `biber` should be available if you have an up to day install of TeXLive.

Comment: @Mark: Biber was not available, so maybe 2009 (in the Ubuntu reps) isn't up to day.

Comment: Ah, yes Ubuntu is running a scarily old version of TeXLive. If it becomes an issue then installing a newer TeXLive is not difficult.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must either use `biber` as backend or (in case `biber` isn't available) issue `\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}` in the preamble. Consider to use `latexmk` to compile your `.tex` document -- it will automatically detect if `bibtex` or `biber` should be used as a backend.

See also [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib).