# Citation styles

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)
>   [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles)

I've been using Latex for a while now and I'm very happy with the results. However, there is one exception, namely bibliography. I often have to write papers for different institutions and every institute has its own citation critiria. So far I have tried natbib, jurabib and several others, but none of them could produce satisfying results. Therefore, I gave up after several days of frustration.

What I do now is writing each footnote and every item in my bibliography by hand. Don't ask: it is timeconsuming and error-prone. This has worked so far, because I only had to write papers with 15 pages and 15-20 bibliography items. Now that I have to start writing larger papers, I wanted to revise Latexs capabilities.

I have read that Biblatex is the new kid on the block. Can it solve my problems? How hard would it be to write my own citation style? After all, it is just a concatenation of strings, right?

And if Biblatex is the solution for my problems: Can someome point me to a 'how to get started' tutorial? The manual seems to be too extensive.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! The answers in this question are a good starting-point: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806 However, it would be helpful if you provided some more information about your desired citation-style. Most likely there is a way to realize it via `biblatex`-customizations, but this requires some more input from your side.

Comment: `Biblatex` comes with a bunch of pre-defined styles; have a look at them. If one of them comes halfway close to what you need, chances are good that you don't need to invest too much time to achieve what you need.

Comment: The following may be relevant as well: [How to get started using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38509/how-to-get-started-using-biblatex) and [What to do to switch to biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

Comment: You can find some [biblatex styles on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib).